# Kubernetes "internal only" ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm fairly new to k8s and I'm trying to assemble an internal api infrastructure - meaning it's only available within k8s. I want to be able to map api endpoints the way the ingress controller does for example.

- Service "A" in namespace "X" maps to internal://sales
- Service "B" in namespace "Y" maps to internal://sales/reports

Is there a way to do this without using an ingress controller or by using an ingress controller that's not exposed externally?

Comment: What's the underlying reason you want to use an ingress internally? Maybe there are other solutions to that problem than using an ingress?

Comment: Primarily, I want to use the same internal service / path names for all environments. This will cut down on environment config for each deployment and expedite (a little) bug triage as developers can traverse the logical layers of their applications no mater the environment. From desktop to production.

Comment: In addition, we are constructing an api infrastructure that will get fairly large over time. I want developers to be able to build microservices discretely and then "slot" them into the api's url structure over time. This api is for internal use only so no exposure to the outside world is desired.

Comment: Lastly, this api infrastructure is sort of  a tennant model. Except our administrative systems need acces to all the tennants equally. Imagine an api like this //admin/{::clientId}/users, //admin/{::clientId}/resourceUsage, and so forth. all the paths after {::clientId} are microservices exclusively relating to that client - built and deployed as a unit. The services can vary in terms of cusomization and in resource usage. And they're volitile. Once the clientId has expired (can be a month, can be years) it's services are removed.

Comment: All right. Understood. This kind of multi tenancy setup with isolated/customized workloads is something special. If you want to leverage things like NetworkPolicies later on, a setup with ingress-controller or nginx proxy might get into your way. Here, using direct access and leveraging namespaces could help. Having a namespace per tenant and most services of one customer talking internally, you can make use of short dns names. An admin could issue a call to http://service14.customer123/resourceUsage while another app of customer123 just calls http://service14 from the same namespace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ingress-controller isn't really a special workload compared to other workloads/services deployed to the cluster. Mapping external traffic into the cluster happens because the `Service` of the ingress controller is exposed to the outside (in most cases) using the `type: LoadBalancer` which triggers the cloud infrastructure to provide a public IP and a cloud load balancer that maps to the cluster VMs (on the service exposed ports).

Nobody prevents you from **not** setting that service type to `LoadBalancer` effectively making your ingress-controller internal. If you want to use custom domain names, that will require some DNS CNAME records pointing to your cluster-local service name of the ingress-controller, but that is definitely possible.

Please make sure how your ingress-controller of choice is deployed exactly. Some use `DaemonSet`s and `HostPort`s for performance reasons, which means you need to take extra care for your firewall setup.

Nevertheless, you should consider if you really want to use an ingress-controller here as with running your real services internally, you already have stable DNS names you can use. Using an ingress-controller introduces additional hops of your packets as the request first goes to an ingress controller instance (which could be running on a different node) and then is forwarded to the real target workload.

If you have a fixed set of workloads, you could also go with an nginx deployment to handle that proxying/rewriting of urls and paths. Check [the nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for some sample config. From a networking perspective, that's not really different to the ingress-controller setup and also introduces the additional hop.

Comment: to restate what your saying, I could use an ingress controller by
  
- change the ingress service (nginx in my case) to client-ip to prevent exteneral exposure.
- use nginx url/path rewriting to point to actual installed services.

The major disadvantage for this is the additional hop (and resource consumption I presume).

Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes. And with introducing such a proxy layer (ingress-controller or nginx), you lose the ability to make use of NetworkPolicies because the source of your request will always be the proxying pod, not the real source. I'd propose evaluating a non-proxied setup and making use of the DNS names between services. See my comment on the question, too...